# changing color from white to transparent - UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

i have a image with white lines. I need to change all white colors in image to transparent. I found solutions in obj-c, but it doesn't work.
In image are yellow and red colors too.

My code:

```
   let rawImageRef: CGImageRef = image.CGImage!

    let colorMasking: [CGFloat] = [222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255]
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    let maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), maskedImageRef);
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    self.controlView.image = result!
```

But i don't see anything - image is clear (probably).

What am i doing wrong, please? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

fixed

added code before create rawImageReg:

```
image = UIImage(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!)!
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Colors in UIKit and Cocoa both are specified as floating point numbers from 0..1, not integers from 0..255, the following should fix your problem:

```
let colorMasking : [CGFloat] = [222.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0, ...]
```

Comment: Hmm... looking at the docs for `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` it appears that the masking colors have to be specified in the same "space" as the source image, so depending on the source image you may need ints or floats.

Comment: thanks for answer. i tried your code, but result is same.

Comment: maskedImageRef is nil i don't understand

Comment: If maskedImageRef is nil, that argues that the components array is invalid.  Have you tried using floats instead of ints?

Comment: yes, 222.0, 255.0, 222.0, 255.0, 222.0, 255.0, i tried your solution and int. Nothing. I don't know whats wrong :)